# importerror no module named '_sqlite3' python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I already saw this question in here. 
The last one to try was the below one.

```
pip install pysqlite
```

But it shows

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 98: invalid continuation byte
```

Pls help me. Am using python 3.4

Comment: Why you need to install SQLite3? It ships with Python!

Comment: No module named '_sqlite3' error pops up

Comment: Try importing `sqlite3`, not `_sqlite3`.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.

In linux I had to install sqlite-dev package first and then installed python, then it worked fine.

Just try installing sqlite-dev package and import the module. if this doesn't work you might have to install pysqlite again after installing the sqlite-dev

To install sqlite-dev, you can try

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite(or sqlite-dev) # I don't remember the package name exactly
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to make

```
import sqlite3
```

and it works fine in python 3.4.1

Why you need to use pysqlite ?